# Basic inheritance in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance

I am very new to OOP. And i've read that a derived class can access the public and protected members of base class.

`A.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class A extends Controller
{
      public $x=5;
      public function index()
      {...}
}
```

and `B.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class B extends A
{
     public function index()
     {
          print_r($x);
     }
}
```

why is `$x` not accessed from derived class?
 I have this route:

```
 Route::get('/B/index','B@index');
```

I got the error:

> undefined variable x.

Comment: You are calling a function directly from the class `B`'s body. You need to wrap it in a method. Also update your question and tell us what error you receive.

Comment: @linuxartisan i receive undefined variable x.

Answer (score 3):

Make the following changes in your code:

```
class B extends A
{
     public function get()
     {
         echo $this->x;  // will echo the value in variable $x;
     }
}

$obj = new B;
$obj->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

Please change code as bellow. it will show result.

```
class A
{
      public $x=5; //or protected $x=5;
      public function index()
      {
        echo "A";
      }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function index()
    {
       echo $this->x;   
    }

}

$classB = new B();
$classB->index();
```

you can use :http://phptester.net/ to test online

**I Hope help you**

Comment: If you want run echo "A". Please use $classA = new A(); $classA->index(); Thank!